# now() not recognized within a module

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.7, python-datetime

I have a module which contains a timestamp used by other functions within the module

```
import datetime, time
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
def tsp():           #Timestamp
    return datetime.now().strftime("%x %X") + '\n'
```

If this same code is included directly as a function in a jupyter notebook, it works.

```
import datetime, time
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

def tsp(full=False):           #Timestamp
    return datetime.now().strftime("%x %X") + '\n'

#import test_tsp
#from test_tsp import *
print('Hello '+tsp())
```

Hello 10/15/21 15:59:05

Commenting out the "def", and uncommenting the 2 import statements, and the error message pops up:

```
     23 def tsp():           #Timestamp
---> 24     return datetime.now().strftime("%x %X") + '\n'
     25 
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'
```

I have tried `datetime.datetime.now()`, `datetime.now()`, and `now()`. Same error. python version 3.7

Comment: If you have `from datetime import ...`, then you don't need `import datetime`

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: @roganjosh But `from datetime import datetime` should make the extra qualification unnecessary.

Comment: Are you sure you have that `from` line in the module version?

Comment: This is true. `import datetime as dt` is my 100% go-to and it just avoids ambiguity

Comment: I wish the class `datetime` was not in a module also named `datetime`. The module name is fine (though `datetimeutils` might have been more descriptive); the class name should have been something like `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks - but the exact same code works when directly in the main code. Why? Copied from module. And copied into main notebook and it runs. Same imports in main code, also. Again, tried all of datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.now(), and now(). Same error.

Comment: @chepner Agree about the duplication. But for whatever reason, most of the built-in modules don't follow the convention of capitalized class names. (notable exception: `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter`)

Comment: if you use `import datetime` then you should use `datetime.datetime.now()`. If you import `from datetime import datetime` then you should use `datetime.now()`. But there can be other problem - you may have own file `datetime.py` and it may import your file and it can't find `now()` in your file. You should check `print( datetime.__file__ )` to see if you impirt own file or module `datetime`. If you have onw file `datetime.py` then you will have to rename it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the code shown. Can you please provide a [mre]? What *else* is there in the module?

Comment: Which python version are you using? And could you write exactly the code you are using? `datetime` at calling point should be the class and not the module, so the error is confusing. Or are you using the function in a body module, before all modules are loaded? (common in circular imports)

Answer (score 1):

try datetime.datetime.now() instead of datetime.now()